# OpenLayers ExportMap control doesn't work

Tags: openlayers

Trying to implement [this example](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/camptocamp/canvas/openlayers/examples/exportMapCanvas.html) to render an image to canvas. Keep getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: exportMap is not defined" for this line:

```
exportMapControl = new OpenLayers.Control.ExportMap();
```

Tested in v2.11 and 2.12. No ExportMap() control exists. Has this functionality been eliminated?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the ExportMap control was created as part of testing how HTML5 works together with Openlayers and as of 2.12 is not yet a tested & deployed feature. [Source](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Future/OpenLayersAndHTML5).